# Is it possible to hide modules from parent layer for modules in child layer in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

Let's consider the following situation. I have two layers:

- boot layer
- mycustom layer

Boot layer is parent of mycustom layer. Beside I have three modules:

- mod.a
- mod.b
- mod.c

In module-info of mod.a I have

```
module mod.a {
   requires mod.b;
}
```

In module-info of mod.c I have

```
module mod.c {
   requires mod.b;
}
```

In boot layer I have mod.a and mod.b. In mycustom layer I have mod.b and mod.c (I want to have mod.b in this layer for some reasons). However, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.module.ResolutionException: mod.c reads more than one module named mod.b.

Is it possible to "hide" mod.b in boot layer for modules in mycustom layer? If yes, then how?

This is the way I create mycustom layer:

```
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(...);
ModuleLayer parent = ModuleLayer.boot();
Configuration cf = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of("mod.b, mod.c"));
ClassLoader scl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ModuleLayer myCustomLayer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cf, scl);
```

Comment: *I want to have mod-b in this layer for some reasons*... could you explain  those, just in case there could probably be an alternate of what you're trying to achieve anyway.

Comment: Also thinking about the lines of *removing mod-b from the boot layer*, I remember there was a similar question from you on removing a module from a layer. But if you keep deleting the posts and open new every time the context or any useful information there is lost.

Comment: Can you edit the question to indicate the relationship between the modules (the `requires transitive` in particular). I assume the issue is that mod-a requires transitive mod-b, and mod-c requires both mod-a and b-mob. In that scenario: mod-c will read mod-a and mod-b in the boot layer, and also mod-b in the custom layer.

Comment: @Alan Bateman I edited the question.

Comment: There isn't enough here to diagnose this. Are you sure that there isn't any `requires transitive` in the picture? Also are you sure that mod.c doesn't require any other modules?

Comment: @AlanBateman I am 100% sure that there is no `requires transitive` in any modules. Mod.c can require other modules.

Comment: I can't explain the exception from the information you've revealed so far. The exception arises because mod.c is reading mod.b in the boot layer - this arises mod.c requires a module in the boot layer that `requires transitive mod.b`.

Comment: @Alan Bateman Ok. Could you say if there is any API to `hide` modules from parent layer?

Comment: A child layer may contain a module with the same name as a module in a parent layer, it shadows/hides the module in the parent layer. Implied readability complicates this a bit because a configuration may contain modules X and Y where X does not directly require Y but it does read Y in a parent layer because it requires (and thus reads) a module in a parent layer that requires transitive Y. If you can reveal more about the modules in the picture then it should be possible to diagnose the issue are you seeing.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thank you very much for detailed explanation.